# How to cross-group on two columns in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have a personal message system on my website, which is pretty easy.
But I would like to have an administrator page where all conversations are shown between users and their amount of messages.

So the table looks like (simplified version):

```
CREATE TABLE pm (
    id        INT(10)     NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    from      INT(10)     NOT NULL REFERENCES (usertable),
    to        INT(10)     NOT NULL REFERENCES (usertable),
    message   BLOB        NOT NULL
);
```

Example:

Say I have some users: Mark, John, Bryan and Kate.

Mark (from) sends 5 messages to John (to) and John (from) sends 3 messages to Mark (to).

Kate (from) sends 2 messages to Bryan (to) and Bryan (from) sends 1 message to Kate (to).

I would like a result set that shows

> Mark - John  - 8 messages
>
> Kate - Bryan - 3 messages

And this for all users in my table at once.

I'm really stuck on this and I have searched everywhere but have not found a solution.
The difficulty lies in the fact that I want all users listed and I have to cross the "from" and "to" column somehow...

I hope anyone will be able to help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select from_id, to_id, count(*) count_between
from
(
    select from_id, to_id from pm
    union all
    select to_id, from_id from pm
) combined
where from_id < to_id
group by from_id, to_id
```

Full sample

```
CREATE TABLE pm (from_id int,to_id int);
insert pm select 1,2;
insert pm select 1,2;
insert pm select 1,2;
insert pm select 1,2;
insert pm select 1,2;
insert pm select 2,1;
insert pm select 2,1;
insert pm select 2,1;
insert pm select 3,4;
insert pm select 3,4;
insert pm select 4,3;

select from_id, to_id, count(*) count_between
from
(
    select from_id, to_id from pm
    union all
    select to_id, from_id from pm
) combined
where from_id < to_id
group by from_id, to_id

--- results
from_id     to_id       count_between
----------- ----------- -------------
1           2           8
3           4           3
```

To turn the IDs into names, use the normal to `user` table or some such. e.g.

```
select u1.name from_, u2.name to_, count(*) count_between
from
(
    select from_id, to_id from pm
    union all
    select to_id, from_id from pm
) combined
join users u1 on u1.id = combined.from_id
join users u2 on u2.id = combined.to_id
where from_id < to_id
group by u1.name, u2.name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a conversation pair unique by listing the person with the largest id first.  Then you can group by the id's of both persons:

```
select  ut1.name
,       ut2.name
,       convo_pairs.message_count
from    (
        select  case when [from] < [to] then [to] else [from] end as p1
        ,       case when [from] < [to] then [from] else [to] end as p2
        ,       count(*) as message_count
        from    pm
        group by
                case when [from] < [to] then [to] else [from] end as p1
        ,       case when [from] < [to] then [from] else [to] end as p2
        ) as convo_pairs
join    usertable ut1
on      ut1.id = convo_pairs.p1
join    usertable ut2
on      ut2.id = convo_pairs.p2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select ISNULL(a.from,b.from) + '-' + ISNULL(a.to,b.to) + '-' +  convert(varchar(a.count+b.count)) + 'messages' 
(select pm1.from,pm1.to,count(1) count
from pm pm1
group by pm1.from,pm1.to) a FULL OUTER 
(select pm1.from,pm1.to,count(1) count 
from pm pm1
group by pm1.from,pm1.to) b
on a.from=b.to
and a.to=b.from
```